# We need to be more polite with new users and amateurs

Tags: discussion

This [question was closed](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/15538/will-iran-get-hurt-in-this-way) even before have a proper explanation of why it was closed and doesn't even have some explanation of why the question was closed, with the exception of one comment that encourage the new user to be more *objective* in the topic.

Being an old user, the comments seems to be correct but for someone who is not familiar with SE itself, won't have any sense. We need to be more **politically correct** with new users, so I encourage to all users that see newbies to:

- Tell them what's wrong with the question: Guide them to write a nice question. Even if you don't like the question, help the question to be as clear as possible.
- Ask them to take the [Politics.SE Tour](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour): When I made my first question here, take the tour helped me understand what is this place about. Some people came from other sites like Quora where the edition is not their best strength. A little guide is useful

Otherwise, we're not encouraging people to ask question, they leave without nothing.

Comment: It is hard to justify putting effort into educating new users that put basically no effort into asking their own question and include a potentially inflammatory image in the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is definitely correct, and a problem at most stackexchange sites.

When voting to close a question - especially those of first-posters - it would be ideal to leave a comment including (sorted):

- stating a reason for a close vote
- linking to the tour/help center/on-topic FAQ
- a suggestion on how to improve the question and make in on-topic
- a welcome to the site
- linking to any other relevant meta posts

Voting to close is easy. Leaving a comment is work, so many people don't do it (me included).

Having templates ready for the most common close reasons - including the links to the appropriate meta posts - makes this easier. Some sites have meta posts for this, for an example see [codereview.SE](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4952/frequently-posted-comments).

Answer (score 9):

Usually on SE we like to judge content, and not the poster of this content.  One of the implications of this is that we are as hard on content from new users as we are on content from old users.

The question, as it was was poorly written, and that's a perfectly valid reason to downvote it, and since we close questions which are unclear, it is a valid reason to close too.

In the meantime, I've cleaned up the question a bit and reopened it.

Comment: I completely agree with you but since the user is new and don't have any experience, would be more productive if we try to show how the site works. In the meantime, the actions taken were correct.

Comment: In support of @nelruk's comment, we can be polite and even helpful to new users (and indeed to any users) despite judging the content of their contributions negatively. Refraining from judging users doesn't mean that we need to treat new and experienced users identically, particularly when itcomes to "you should know better" comments or to unexplained downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely would encourage them to take the tour, but also send them to the help center (maybe saying which pages are the most important), and to the faq. I would also encourage **point**ing **out specific problems in their posts**, and maybe also referring them to meta.

But most of all, Be Nice! I cannot overstate how important being nice is. If you go somewhere, and the first few responses to your question is mean, you’re probably going to leave and never come back.